# How to use node streams to insert big data into mysql?

Tags: mysql, node.js, stream

I'm trying to use node stream to insert 10 million records into mysql. Is there a way to do this with node stream? I'm not finding very useful or 'friendly' answers or documentation about this issue anywhere. So far I'm able to insert 45K records, but I'm getting some errors trying with a record set any bigger than that.

Also, what's the callback in the code below supposed to do here? I'm not sure where I got this code from and I'm not actually passing a call back, so, maybe that's the problem!! :D Any ideas? What would the callback actually be? Maybe the callback is supposed to take chunk and pass a chunk at a time?  How could I rework this to get it to work consistently?  I just don't think this code below is actually splitting the data up into chunks at all. How do I split it up into manageable chunks?

Depending on the amount of records I try this with I get different errors. The errors I am getting are:

For 50K - 80K sometimes I get this error:

```
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
    at Connection._handleConnectTimeout
```

I get this error for 100K records or above:

```
 Error: ER_NET_PACKET_TOO_LARGE: Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes
        at Query.Sequence._packetToError
```

This error for around 55K records:

```
Error: write EPIPE
    at WriteWrap.afterWrite [as oncomplete] (net.js:788:14)
```

It's kind of wild to get 3 different errors depending on the amount of records I'm trying to insert.

Here's the code (It's working fine for 45000 records, but not for anything bigger):

```
var db = require('./index.js');
var faker = require('faker');
var stream = require('stream');

var songs = [];

var size = 10000000; 

var songList = function(){
  for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      var song = [i, faker.random.words(1,2), faker.name.findName(), faker.internet.url(1,50), faker.random.words(1,2), faker.random.words(1,20)];
      songs.push(song);  
    }
  console.log('songs', songs);  
  return songs;
}

var songSql = "INSERT INTO songs (song_id, song_name, artist, song_url, song_album, song_playlist) VALUES ?";

var songValues = songList();

var songSeed = function() {
  console.log('x: ', x);
  var query = db.connection.query(songSql, [songValues]).stream({highWaterMark: 5});
  var testStream = new stream.Transform({highWaterMark: 5, objectMode: true});
  testStream._write = function(chunk,encoding,callback) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('my chunk: ', chunk);
      callback();
    },1000);
  }
  // Pipe the query stream into the testStream
  query.pipe(testStream)

  // Monitor data events on the side to see when we pause
  query.on("result",function(d,i) {
  console.log("Data Sent")
  })
}

songSeed();
```

Comment: I guess this stream implementation depends on what's inside `index.js`, but apparently it doesn't really stream the content, just chunks it. (Not sure MySQL allows streaming in, although CLI piping is a bit like that.) Your timeout error is your lower bound: MySQL cannot process that many rows fast enough. The max packet happens even earlier: network saturated (so it means MySQL didn't even tried to understand the query, so it's not a stream). The pipe error I'm not sure.

Comment: Just had a look at NPM package `mysql`, which seems to match your code. In it, the [streaming functionality](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/blob/8ae456f54d346dc84d49bba5a01888653ba2981b/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js#L182) is made only for retrieving results, not pushing data. Hence timeouts and packets too large: it's sending all values in one request.

Comment: LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE would be a good interface for this however it appears to [have issues](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/issues/2144)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the MySQL server increase [max_allowed_packet](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) to 1G. There's no real downside to this.

Comment: batching records to 100k insert rows at a time would be quite sane too.